# How can I send DPAD_LEFT/DPAD_RIGHT key events from my app to the active activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to send DPAD key events from my service to the active activity. 
This is not a commercial app, and I won't distribute it. It is only for my own use. So any suggestion which does not include "root"ed devices , I can use.

I can do it with ADB using commands like "KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN_LEFT"

however, this is not available for a normal app. (I tried runtime.exec) it's not permitted.

How can I achieve this with any method ? (accessibility, special permissions , etc.)

thanks.